# How to extract all rows which is duplicates in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get all rows which is the same name and location from **Users Table**

```
**id** |name        |location    |phone_number

1      |John        | Europe     |0988884434

2      |john        | Europe        |0933333333

3      |Michael     |Europe      |0888888888

4      |Smith       |Dubai       |082388888888

5      |Smith       |Dubai      | 03939494944
```

I want to get **all rows** which is the same name and location like

```
john  |Europe

john  |Europe

Smith |Dubai

Smith |Dubai
```

here is how i tried to do

```
$duplicates = DB::table('users')
->select('name','location', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
->groupBy('name', 'location')
->having('count', '>', 1)
->get();
```

but this is just showing only one row which is duplicates like

```
john |Europe
Smith|Dubai
```

Any help or advice you have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25):

Use `havingRaw`:

```
$duplicates = DB::table('users')
->select('name','location', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
->groupBy('name', 'location')
->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
->get();
```

I also wasn't sure of the syntax, but the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) seems to imply that the alias you defined in the select clause is not available in the normal `having()` function.

Answer (score 3):

To get **All Rows** rather than a total count of a group of duplicate rows would look like the following;

```
$duplicates = DB::table('users')
->select('id', 'name', 'location')
->whereIn('id', function ($q){
            $q->select('id')
            ->from('users')
            ->groupBy('name', 'location')
            ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1');
})->get();
```

Comment: I tryed DB::table('categories')->select('id', 'slug')->whereIn('id', function ($q){$q->select('id')->from('categories')->groupBy('slug')->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1');})->get(); but get this: 'dbtable.categories.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `id`, `slug` from `categories` where `id` in (select `id` from `categories` group by `slug` having COUNT(*) > 1))